# DEBIAN minimum hard disk footprint

Tags: debian, installation

I found this [Red Hat server minimal install](https://serverfault.com/questions/29071/red-hat-server-minimal-install) question while searching google for debian minimal install.

User shylent wrote thet he uses really basic debian install so small that processes can count on one hand fingers :D.

So Im searching and asking for starting point to create basic linux distro but not from scratch like LFS but make linux distro based on debian for example.

I used debootstrap but still it is 150M large.

Comment: What do you need such a small setup for?  Given that storage is so cheap under most conditions is it really worth the effort to try to save a few MB here and there?

Comment: learning purpose

Comment: One of the things you can do after debootstrap is to prune the things you dont' need.  Man pages, /usr/share/doc.  You may be able to shave a few mb off of it by looking here @ there for extras that are nice to have in a base system, but not required for base functionality.

Answer (score 1):

What are your requirements for the system?  The Debian mini.iso install disk which is arguably a version Debian disk weights in at about 8-12MB depending on arch.  But, that disk is really only useful for doing installs.

If you expect to run applications you will probably need to include lots of libraries and related tools or recompile things to only have the features that are essential to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to learn linux generally and create distro that suits my needs for home server. But I want it to be debian based. and lowest possibile footprint on hard disk and memory.

Answer (score 0):

[Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) is based on Debian. The development has been pretty much non-existent lately, but I run it on a P3 733Mhz/32MB Sony laptop that i converted to a picture frame and it's plenty fast even for that hardware